How to automate type generation by orval on the client sidep
I am generating types on client side by running orval plugin over server side’s yaml file.
I am manually porting the yaml file from server project to client side project to generate types.
Can this process be automated?
Can i configure orval to swagger doc so that types are generated automaticallyvs porting the yaml file from server project
